# Is `arc4random` secure enough?

Tags: cryptography, random, unix, c

I need to generate many many initialization vectors and session keys in C++ code. I am wondering if `arc4random` is up to the task. Last I heard, there are many weaknesses in the RC4 cipher. Should I stick to reading from `/dev/urandom` instead?

I am only targeting Unix-like OS, not Windows.

Comment: is it possible (by your crypto library) to use a proper CSPRNG? something like Yarrow / Fortuna / AES-CTR-DRBG / HMAC-DRBG / X9.62C-PRNG ?

Comment: @SOJPM: I am using Apple's CommonCrypto API, which according to my cursory survey include no random number generator.

Comment: the documentation I found claims /dev/random to be safe for crypto purposes. However you can also build your own PRNG by using the output of /dev/random as IV and key for AES-CTR (if available)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both arc4random and /dev/urandom have histories of problems.  Some systems have reimplemented arc4random without RC4, but some systems kept RC4.  I prefer arc4random over /dev/urandom, but if your goal is to avoid RC4, and you have a system where arc4random uses RC4 and /dev/urandom avoids RC4, then you would prefer /dev/urandom.

**These systems have arc4random without RC4:**

- [OpenBSD 5.5 (May 1, 2014)](http://www.openbsd.org/55.html) switched arc4random to ChaCha20.
- [NetBSD 7 (Oct 8, 2015)](http://www.netbsd.org/releases/formal-7/NetBSD-7.0.html) switched arc4random to ChaCha20.
- [libbsd 0.8.0 (Nov 30, 2015)](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85827) switched arc4random to ChaCha20.  (libbsd provides arc4random for systems like GNU/Linux.)
- [macOS 10.2 (Sep 20, 2016)](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1158.1.2/gen/FreeBSD/arc4random.c.auto.html) seems to have switched arc4random to AES.
- [Android (unknown version)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/0468feb28696751efcddada8de69a622afffdba8) switched arc4random to ChaCha20.
- [Illumos (unknown version)](https://www.illumos.org/issues/5830) added arc4random with ChaCha20.

**These use RC4:** As of 2017, both [DragonFly BSD](http://gitweb.dragonflybsd.org/dragonfly.git/blob/32cfd90abb8f7f3ac599de95e6da27afe5b1c771:/lib/libc/gen/arc4random.c) and [FreeBSD](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libc/gen/arc4random.c?revision=315225&view=markup) kept arc4random with RC4.

**These problems can happen with arc4random:** Fortunately, none of these problems happen if your system has fixed arc4random.

- arc4random might use RC4.
- arc4random might use an improved RC4 that discards the first few hundred bytes after keying the stream, but it might not discard enough bytes.
- arc4random might fail to detect a fork.  After the fork, both processes would get identical random numbers.
- arc4random might fail to get entropy from the kernel, then seed itself using only gettimeofday and getpid, then generate predictable and insecure numbers.  In DragonFly BSD and FreeBSD, [the sysctl to get entropy should never fail](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=306636), so arc4random should never reach the code to use only gettimeofday and getpid.

**These problems can happen with /dev/urandom:** Unfortunately, some of these problems don't have a fix.

- /dev/urandom can use RC4.  It did in OpenBSD before 5.5.  In most other systems, /dev/urandom never used RC4.
- /dev/urandom might not exist.  This might happen inside a chroot.  Some setups don't allow device nodes like /dev/urandom inside the chroot.
- The program might fail to open /dev/urandom because it has reached the limit on file descriptors.  This might not be a problem if the program doesn't open lots of files, or if it opens /dev/urandom early.
- Multi-core machines might slow down, if multiple cores are reading /dev/urandom, but the kernel uses only core to generate the random numbers.  This might not be a problem if you have few cores or don't need too many random bytes.

Because of the last 3 problems (chroot, fd limit, multiple cores), I prefer arc4random over /dev/urandom.

**There is a third option:** Instead of arc4random or /dev/urandom, you might use a crypto library with a secure random number generator.

[GnuTLS uses ChaCha or AES](http://nmav.gnutls.org/2017/08/gnutls-3-6-0.html) for random numbers.  [NSS uses SHA-256](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=457045) for random.  [OpenSSL seems to be switching from SHA-1 to AES](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/4019) for random.  All three libraries (GnuTLS, NSS, OpenSSL) seem to avoid RC4 for random numbers.

[LibreSSL might call arc4random and use RC4](https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable/blob/5afc4e3cd855e7726a2b614d7004699ed727ec0d/m4/check-os-options.m4) in systems like DragonFly BSD.  Therefore, you can't trust LibreSSL to avoid RC4.

Some people have spread [doubt about random numbers from userspace](http://sockpuppet.org/blog/2014/02/25/safely-generate-random-numbers/).  These people oppose userspace generators (like arc4random, GnuTLS, NSS, [OpenSSL](https://emboss.github.io/blog/2013/08/21/openssl-prng-is-not-really-fork-safe/), and [OpenSSL again](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/367)) and prefer /dev/urandom for random numbers.  This might have influenced [Ruby to prefer /dev/urandom over OpenSSL](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9569).  I prefer the userspace libraries because of my above list of problems with /dev/urandom.

Answer (score 3):

You should stick with /dev/urandom. Thomas Hühn has a good overview at http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/

If you are really concerned you can look at using a user space CSPRNG. Stick with well understood CSPRNGs (e.g. Blum Blum Shub, although it has some performance issues) and respected implementations.

You might want to read http://www.cypherpunks.to/~peter/06_random.pdf and http://cs.ucsb.edu/~koc/cren/project/pp/gawande-mundle.pdf.

Of course, you should also review the source code of any CSPRNG if this is really important for your application.

Comment: The problem with `/dev/urandom` is that my application is multithreaded but `/dev/urandom` is serialized.

Answer (score 2):

RC4 has its flaws and arc4random specifically had some issues about 7 years ago (CVE-2008-5162) yet it is expected to be secured

Also, note that urandom is not the best idea or as Wikipedia says:

> A counterpart to /dev/random is /dev/urandom ("unlimited"[5]/non-blocking random source[4]) which reuses the internal pool to produce more pseudo-random bits. This means that the call will not block, but the **output may contain less entropy** than the corresponding read from /dev/random. While it is still intended as a pseudorandom number generator suitable for most cryptographic purposes, it is not recommended for the generation of long-term cryptographic keys.

As entropy is the one thing you really crave for in PRNGs, this compromise may end in a compromised app.

Comment: If you do a bit of digging you'll discover that /dev/random and /dev/urandom use identical methods to create random numbers. The difference being that /dev/random estimates the "entropy" and blocks if there is insufficient "entropy".

Comment: And that is why it's better for crypto usage, if we are counting on its "entropy assesment" mechanism.

Comment: Meanwhile found this nice page, that almost convinced me that I'm wrong:
http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/

Comment: @GalB1t that was the page I was about to sending ;) If the Application is not startet at startup urandom is more then enough. Problem with random is that it will blocks and the missing entropy is only a issue when the device is fresh started

Comment: Also, missing entropy can mostly fixed with _havege_